# CMD Server Start

Tags: batch-file, cmd, server

hello can someone help me, please?^^

**my server starter old version:**

> echo   Maps:
>
> echo   1. mp_1a
>
> echo   2. mp_2b
>
> echo   3. mp_3c
>
> echo   4. mp_4d
>
> set /p MAP=Enter your desired map name:
>
> cls
>
> echo   Gamemodes:
>
> echo   game=TDM
>
> echo   game=DM
>
> set /p GAME=Enter your gamemode:
>
> Start Server.exe server %MAP%?%GAME%?maxplayers=16

**i try a new version**

> echo   Maps:
>
> echo   1. Map A
>
> echo   2. Map B
>
> echo   3. Map C
>
> echo   4. Map D
>
> set /P wahl=Auswahl
>
> if /i "%wahl%"=="1" goto:map1
>
> if /i "%wahl%"=="2" goto:map2
>
> if /i "%wahl%"=="3" goto:map3
>
> if /i "%wahl%"=="4" goto:map4
>
> :map1
>
> set MAP=mp_1a
>
> :map2
>
> set MAP=mp_2b
>
> :map3
>
> set MAP=mp_3c
>
> :map4
>
> set MAP=mp_4d
>
> cls
>
> echo   Gamemode:
>
> echo   1. DM
>
> echo   2. TDM
>
> set /P wahl=Auswahl
>
> if /i "%wahl%"=="1" goto:game1
>
> if /i "%wahl%"=="2" goto:game2
>
> :game1
>
> set GAME=game_DM
>
> :game2
>
> set GAME=game_TDM
>
> Start Server.exe server %MAP%?%GAME%?maxplayers=16

**the new version is easy, but it don't set the %MAP% and %GAME% -.-**

**THANK YOU lit**

**for all my changes ;)**

> echo   Maps:
>
> echo   1. Map A
>
> echo   2. Map B
>
> echo   3. Map C
>
> echo   4. Map D
>
> set /P wahl=Auswahl
>
> if /i "%wahl%"=="1" goto:map1
>
> if /i "%wahl%"=="2" goto:map2
>
> if /i "%wahl%"=="3" goto:map3
>
> if /i "%wahl%"=="4" goto:map4
>
> :map1
>
> set MAP=mp_1a
>
> **goto:gamemod**
>
> :map2
>
> set MAP=mp_2b
>
> **goto:gamemod**
>
> :map3
>
> set MAP=mp_3c
>
> **goto:gamemod**
>
> :map4
>
> set MAP=mp_4d
>
> **goto:gamemod**
>
> cls
>
> **:gamemod**
>
> echo   Gamemode:
>
> echo   1. DM
>
> echo   2. TDM
>
> set /P wahl=Auswahl
>
> if /i "%wahl%"=="1" goto:game1
>
> if /i "%wahl%"=="2" goto:game2
>
> :game1
>
> set GAME=game_DM
>
> **goto:start**
>
> :game2
>
> set GAME=game_TDM
>
> **goto:start**
>
> **:start**
>
> Start Server.exe server %MAP%?%GAME%?maxplayers=16

Comment: Can you add some more details on the code you shared?

Comment: thats all, i will make a server start cmd/exe, to start easy and fix a server, without new shortcuts, i change fix map and gamemod and start ;)

Comment: the server start with *Start Server.exe server mp_1a?game_DM?maxplayers=16* or *Server.exe server mp_3c?game_TDM?maxplayers=16*

Comment: Comment out or remove any `ECHO OFF` in the script. Run it and watch each statement. I predict that MAP will always be "mp_4d" and GAME will always be "game_TDM" because after they are set the code falls through to set the next one.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the execution of each step. Note that after setting MAP or GAME, it falls through to set the next value. This code has a GOTO to skip to the end of MAP setting and GAME setting. When you see that the code is doing the right thing, remove the `echo` statements at the end and remove the `echo` from the start statement.

```
echo Maps:
echo 1. Map A
echo 2. Map B
echo 3. Map C
echo 4. Map D

set /P wahl=Auswahl

if /i "%wahl%"=="1" goto:map1
if /i "%wahl%"=="2" goto:map2
if /i "%wahl%"=="3" goto:map3
if /i "%wahl%"=="4" goto:map4

:map1
set "MAP=mp_1a" & GOTO AfterMap
:map2
set "MAP=mp_2b" & GOTO AfterMap
:map3
set "MAP=mp_3c" & GOTO AfterMap
:map4
set "MAP=mp_4d" & GOTO AfterMap

:AfterMap
cls

echo Gamemode:
echo 1. DM
echo 2. TDM

set /P wahl=Auswahl

if /i "%wahl%"=="1" goto:game1
if /i "%wahl%"=="2" goto:game2

:game1
set "GAME=game_DM" & GOTO AfterGame
:game2
set "GAME=game_TDM" & GOTO AfterGame

:AfterGame

echo MAP is set to %MAP%
echo GAME is set to %GAME%

echo     Start Server.exe server %MAP%?%GAME%?maxplayers=16
```

Comment: @Tobi - If this works for you, please click on the arrow to indicate that it is the correct answer. Thanks.